# How to set "BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ENVIRONMENT_SETUP" in buildroot

Tags: makefile, buildroot, toolchain

I want to various projects for various platforms, and as such I've concluded that the easiest way to to this is probably going to just have buildroot create the toolchain and then alter the environment to use said toolchain.

From section 8.14.1 of the [buildroot manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.pdf):

> For your convenience, by selecting the option
> BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ENVIRONMENT_SETUP, you can get setup-environment
> script installed in output/host/and therefore in your SDK. This script
> can be sourced with .  your/sdk/path/environment-setup to export a
> number of environment variables that will help cross-compile your
> projects using the Buildroot SDK: the PATH will contain the SDK
> binaries, standard autotools variables will be defined with the
> appropriate values, and CONFIGURE_FLAGS will contain basic ./configure
> options to cross-compile autotools projects. It also provides some
> useful commands. Note however that once this script is sourced, the
> environment is setup only for cross-compilation, and no longer for
> native compilation.

Alright, that sounds pretty much like exactly what I want. However, I have not figured out how to set BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ENVIRONMENT_SETUP. I found no mention of anything similar when looking through `make menuconfig`, I tried to grep the entire buildroot source tree for that string with no luck, and simply exporting it as an environment variabl did not produce a different result either. So, how do I set BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ENVIRONMENT_SETUP, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled across the same problem.  The option was submitted in [April 2020](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2020-April/281535.html), so buildroot-2020.02.8 (the long term support version as of writing) doesn't support it, whereas the PDF available online is newer -- I suspect you are using the same version; the buildroot download page presents the longer term support version first.

Comment: Correct, I forgot to update this question with my findings. Downloading a new version of bulidroot solved the issue. It was somewhere in the `make menuconfig`, I can't remember where.

Answer (score 1):

In menu-config, you do a search ("/") of HOST_ENVIRONMENT and then you find your answer:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfXlH.png)